# bash script read server and not read password

Tags: bash

I use  curl to open with username and password router

```
curl http://192.168.1.1 --user admin:admin |grep -i "stats"
```

But when I made this code to use curl from bash script I have problem to read server and password from file `LINKS_FILE="server"

```
PASS="passwd"
for link in `cat "$LINKS_FILE"`
do
for pass in `cat "$PASS"`
do
res=$(curl -m 1   "http://${link}:8080" --user admin:${pass} )          
if echo $res | grep -i "stats"; then `
```

Comment: ["How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: thanks Ḟḹáḿíṅḡ Ⱬỏḿƀíé but can you give me example with my code bec in new in bash thanks